# How can we remove tweets from a specific user (user with high number of tweets) for sentiment analysis using R?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

Aim: To perform sentiment analysis on historical judgement by usa courts on same sex marriage. 
    # Since the no of tweets were extremely high for some users, it may introduce bias. how can we remove them?
    # Also, why the number of unique tweets in usafull and total are different?

```
    rm(list=ls())
    library(twitteR)
    library(wordcloud)
    library(tm)

    download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",   destfile="cacert.pem")

    consumer_key <- 'key'
    consumer_secret <- 'secret'
    access_token <- 'key'
    access_secret <- 'secret'
    setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)


    usa <- searchTwitter("#LoveWins", n=1500 , lang="en")

    usa2 <- searchTwitter("#LGBT", n=1500 , lang="en")

    usa3 <- searchTwitter("#gay", n=1500 , lang="en")

#get the text
    tusa <- sapply(usa, function(x) x$getText())
    tusa2 <- sapply(usa2, function(x) x$getText())
    tusa3 <- sapply(usa3, function(x) x$getText())

#join texts
    total <- c(tusa,tusa2,tusa3)

#remove the duplicated tweets
    total <- total[!duplicated(total)]

#no. of unique tweets
    uni <- length(total)

# merging three set of tweets horozontally
    usafull<-c(usa,usa2,usa3)

#convert the tweets into dafa frame
    usafull <- twListToDF(usafull)
    usafull <- unique(usafull)

#to know the dates of the tweets (date formatting)
    usafull$date <- format(usafull$created, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
    table(usafull$date)

#make a table of number of tweets per user in decreasing number of tweets
    tdata <- as.data.frame(table(usafull$screenName))
    tdata <- tdata[order(tdata$Freq, decreasing = T), ]
    names(tdata) <- c("User","Tweets")
    head(tdata)


# plot the freq of tweets over time in two hour windows
    library(ggplot2)
    minutes <-60
    ggplot(data = usafull, aes(x=created))+geom_bar(aes(fill=..count..),    binwidth =60*minutes)+scale_x_datetime("Date")+ scale_y_continuous("Frequency")


#plot the table above for the top 30 to identify any unusual trends
    par(mar=c(5,10,2,2))
    with(tdata[rev(1:30), ], barplot(Tweets, names=User, horiz = T, las =1,     main="Top 30: Tweets per user", col = 1))

# the twitter users with more than 20 tweets for removing bias
    userid <- tdata[(tdata$Tweets>20),]
    userid <- userid[,1]
```

Comment: As far as I remember, the screen names of users will be in `usafull$screenName`. So should be able to remove users with specific screen names - let's say screenname1 and 2 - by calling `usafull[!usafull$screenName %in% c("screenname1", "screenname2"), ]` for example. Also, you can identify the duplicated rows by calling `usafull[duplicated(usafull), ]` to examine why unique and total differ.

Comment: Why not just normalize the data after the sentiment classification?

Comment: Yes, your idea works, but for getting the text from the rest of the users after filtering, I'm not able to use the `sapply`. This is the output: `> new <- sapply(usafull_nobias, function(x) x$getText())
Error in x$getText : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` @lukeA

Comment: Can you please elaborate the idea of normalizing the data? @hrbrmstr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I understand you want to remove tweets in `userid`, one way to do it would be like this,

```
usafull_nobias <- subset(usafull, !(screenName %in% userid$User))
```

As for the reason why you get different number of tweets in `total` and `usafull`, it is probably due to the fact that in `total` you are using the text the tweets to find duplicates, and in `usafull` you are using the full tweet; take into account that e.g. retweets might have the same text but might come from different users, have different ids, etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! Yes, It helped! But I encountered another problem which is, `usafull_nobias` has changed and now I am not able to use `sapply` to get the text for further cleaning and analysis.

Comment: Can I proceed further like this, `text <- usafull_nobias$text` and `unique()`for cleaning and analysis instead of using `sapply` function? ( I'm asking since, by far every code for sentiment analysis I have seen, had `sapply`)

Comment: What do you mean by "`usafull_nobias` has changed"? Anyway, you should be able to access the text using `usafull_nobias$text`

Comment: Yes, you can use `text <- usafull_nobias$text` with no problem. `text` is a column of the dataframe `usafull_nobias`. `sapply` applies the function over the list, but in this case the column already exists, there is no need to apply the function.

Comment: What about the different number of tweets in `total` and `usafull`? Did you figure that one out?

Comment: yeah! I got you. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! If your question is solved, please accept the answer. If you've still got issues, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Irnzcig  Hi! I faced another problem..  Since, `searchTwitter()` got only the recent tweets, the tweets were not related to the judgement and I specified 'since' and 'until' like this. `usa1 <- searchTwitter("#LoveWins", n=1500 , lang="en", since='2015-06-26', until='2015-06-28')`
 and got this error `Warning message:
In doRppAPICall("search/tweets", n, params = params, retryOnRateLimit = retryOnRateLimit,  :
  1500 tweets were requested but the API can only return 0` can you help me with this? Thnx for ur time!

Comment: Hi! You've reached twitter rate limits. Take a look to [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting). You can use the parameter `retryOnRateLimit` (type ?searchTwitter in R) or you can add `sleep` statements to your program, so that it waits when you know you are approaching the limit. If you just want to fetch those 1500 tweets, you don't need a `sleep` statement, the problem is probably that you've done too many trials in the last 15 minutes.

Comment: And by the way, as a general advice, please try not to ask questions using the StackOverflow comments. Think about comments as something that could be removed eventually. You may either modify your question (you can un-accept my answer if you realize that it does not solve your problem) else you may open a new question. That way, others can reuse the work you do by opening your question and anybody else answering them; they might find an answer for their problem. For example, I've been looking around quickly and there's a few questions already about R and rate limits but none of them is...

Comment: ... none of them is a good answer for the specific problem you explain in your comment.

Comment: Sure. I'm new to Stack Overflow and I'll take ur advice. Thanks! And I got my problem solved. :)

Comment: No problem! I know you're new, you will get to know little by little how SO works best. It's a fantastic place by the way. Glad to guide you through a bit.